# Get Element From List of List (different type) in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Please consider the following code and read my comments. It's pretty self-explanatory what I am looking for.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> str0 = Arrays.asList("alif", "baa", "taa");
        List<Integer> str1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List<Double> str2 = Arrays.asList(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);

        List<Object> everything = Arrays.asList(str0, str1, str2);

        // How can I get an element using index of index, as below
        System.out.println(everything.get(1).get(2));

        // I know this will work, but I don't want to get the element like this
        List<Integer> temp = (List<Integer>) everything.get(1);
        System.out.println(temp.get(2));
    }

}
```

**Is it possible?**

Comment: use `List<List<Object>>` instead of `List<Object>` for `everything`?

Comment: Yup, that would work in this example. But I cannot change types in the project I am working on. Well, I could but it will be too much work to go through 500 lines of code lol

Comment: I am assuming that you want me to change all the lists to `<Object>` and then use `List<List<Object>>` for `everything`? Does that right?